# How can i make the FOR to loop backward ? Getting some errors

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
for (int i = uids.Count; i > 0; i--)
{
    counting += 1;
    if (counting == 30)
        break;
    string currentUidOnServer = uids[i - 1];
    if (!seenUids.Contains(currentUidOnServer))
    {
        OpenPop.Mime.Message unseenMessage = client.GetMessage(i + 1);
        newMessages.Add(unseenMessage);
        seenUids.Add(currentUidOnServer);
        allMessages.Add(unseenMessage);
        int nProgress = (uids.Count - i + 1) * 100 / uids.Count;
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(nProgress, client.GetMessageCount().ToString() + "/" + i);
    }
}
```

The variable uids contain 7038 items.
I want to report to the backgroundworker progresschanged event.
And it does reporting but it did backward started from 7038 and 100%
And i want it to report from 0% to 100% so i changed the FOR to

```
for (int i = uids.Count; i > 0; i--)
```

It was

```
for (int i = 0; i < uids.Count; i++)
```

The first error out of index exception was on the line

```
string currentUidOnServer = uids[i - 1];
```

So i changed it to [i - 1]

Now i'm getting exception on the line

```
OpenPop.Mime.Message unseenMessage = client.GetMessage(i + 1);
```

Since 7038 + 1 not exist.
So i messed it all.

How this two lines i have/had the exceptions should be ?

Comment: Do `for (int i = uids.Count-1; i > 0; i--)` (and it looks like change all your `i-1`'s back to `i`). array[array.Count] doesn't exist, that's why your upward-counting for loop goes to `i < array.Count`, not `i <= array.Count`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the typical way to do this:
    for (int i = uids.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)

Then, use `uids[i]` and maybe `client.GetMessage(i)`, however I have no idea, what "client" is in your code

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in C# (and all the other C-like languages) are zero-indexed, which means that the first item in the array is at position 0.  Attempting to access an array index that is less than 0 or greater than or equal to the number of elements in the array will result in an error as you have seen.

The first form of your loop:

```
for (int i = uids.Count; i > 0; i--)
```

...produces a sequence of numbers (on your 7038-item array) from 7038 down to 1.  Since 7038 is an invalid array index (1 past the end of the array) and the sequence doesn't include 0, the array access expressions in the loop all use `i -1` to shift the entire sequence down by 1.

To properly reverse the `for` without changing any other code you need to produce a sequence from 1 up to 7038, like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= uids.Count; i++)
```

This is the direct opposite form of your original.

Personally I would prefer that the loop variable be the array index most of the time, and my first instinct when I see a `> 0` condition in a `for` statement is that someone forgot to put the `=` in.

Answer (score 0):

You could just reverse your array with Array.reverse() and then iterate over it using i++ as per your original approach

Oops I thought this was JavaScript question lol, o well the approach I said can conceptually be applied to any language, just need to find the array reverse for your language

Comment: that would work, but as said in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3877932(v=vs.110).aspx, "This method is an O(n) operation, where n is the Length of array." It apparently actually moves all the elements to a new location, so it's unnecessarily expensive.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, originally `i` went from 0 to `uids.Count - 1`. If you can get back to that situation, then your formula for `nProgress` should be

```
int nProgress = (i + 1) * 100 / uids.Count;
```